# How do other messaging systems deal with the problems that Zookeeper in Kafka solves?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, distributed-system, consensus

Zookeeper is a coordination service that handles the problem such as -

1. If one node in a cluster goes down, zookeeper will look for another node
2. Handle serialized access to a shared resource
3. Race conditions, deadlocks.

Other popular messaging systems do not have zookeeper. They should certainly be facing the problems that Zookeeper is claiming to solve.

- Q1) Do they have alternative ways to deal with those problems? Throw
  some light on those ways.
- Q2) Have they found a way of co-existing
  with those problems?

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper is used to achieve resource consistency into a distributed system.

Apache Kafka relies on Zookeeper for multiple purpose :

- To persist cluster metadata and topic configuration in reliable way.
- To elect broker controller
- To elect leaders for topic/partitions
- To discover failing brokers
- Etc.

Under the hood,  Zookeeper uses its own protocol (ZAB, Zookeeper Atomic Broodcast) to support data replication, election, failure recovery. But they exist other protocols for reaching consensus in a distributed system such as Paxos and [Raft](https://raft.github.io/).

For instance, Etcd which is used, as an alternative to Zookeepers , by some systems implements the Raft protocol to provide consistency.

Actually, Zookeeper is used by most of the Apache Kafka alternatives :

- Apache Pulsar ([concepts-architecture-overview](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-architecture-overview/))
- Pravega ([pravega-concepts/](http://pravega.io/docs/latest/pravega-concepts/))
- LogDevice ([logdevice.io](http://logdevice.io))

Finally, RabbitMQ which provides distributed queue mechanism called [Quorum Queues](https://next.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html) actually relies on a variant of Raft protocol.

Comment: really love this answer - it covered so much ground.